# Is there a way to schedule automatic WordPress core updates?

Tags: updates, core

Is it possible to take advantage of automatic WordPress core updates but schedule when they occur? I would like to avoid updates happening, say, at 11pm on a Friday, in the event that they cause issues with the site that would require maintenance or intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core updates (as other things that happen without explicit action by admin) *are* scheduled. However WP scheduling system (WP Cron) act on *intervals* (every N seconds) and has certain amount of drift on top since it it triggered by visits to the site.

In a nutshell it's not too favorable to implement more elaborate date/time rulesets into it firing.

You could reverse the logic by *preventing* core updates within certain times, but really I would recommend to stick with security-only auto updates or manual updates altogether if your site is sensitive enough to it.